# "Request Update" or "Needs Reanswer" flag for older questions

Tags: feature-request

Some questions may need trendy answers.

"What is the best software for doing [XYZ]?"

Some one might answer this question with name of particular software, and many other expert vote up for that answer. But that answer might need an update over the period of time.

**Request Update** or **Needs Reanswer** may solve such situations and ask people for updating  their answers.

Please suggest any other ideas to tackle such situations.

Comment: That is one of the reasons why these kind of questions are not good for this site.

Comment: These kind of questions are off-topic anyway and should get closed.

Comment: ok accepted for "what is the best..." scenario. No offence. Now please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications in above question if after some years future release of PHP has multi-threading support dont u think the above question needs re-answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea.

First we don't want to support "what is the best..." questions because they tend to become subjective popularity contetst.

If you find a question that has an outdated answer you can do the following:

- Give a current answer.
- If the change is minor, you can edit the answer.
- Comment the answer, preferably with a link to the appropriate source.
- Put a bounty on the question, pointimng that the accepted answer is outdated.
- If you are the question asker, you can un-accept the accepted answer.

Comment: ok accepted for "what is the best..." scenario. No offence. Now please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

in above question if after some years future release of PHP has multi-threading support dont u think the above question needs re-answer?